# How to pass id to JavaScript from the parent form

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

Lets say we have this code

```
<h:form id="#{id}">
    <h:panelGroup id="#{id}suggestionPanel">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:inputText value="#{searchString}"
                         rendered="#{validationId == null}"
                         id="#{id}search"
                         onkeyup="autocompleteHandler(this.value)"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Is there a possibility to pass into the JavaScript method called "autocompleteHandler" the Id of the form, or get the Id trough other means then getElementById.

Comment: Please provide a valid JSF code in order to get a real solution to your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And why in your oppinion is this code not valid?

Comment: To start with, you can't assign the ID of a JSF component with `#{someBean.someValue}`. Have you at least tried to make a JSF page with the code you provide?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well you are not right my friend. I never set an id of a JSF component to `#{someBean.someValue}`, those are all strings. On the id=" part you wont se a "dot", for instance its "#{id}search". And **id** is an elvariable that resolves to String.

Please read some jsf documentation before you pass sentence to someone.

FYI: an elvariable is declared like this:
`<!--@elvariable id="id" type="java.lang.String"-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I figured out a way how to get the Id of the outer form, so I wanna share it with you.
This doesn't limit you to an input tag or something.

the javascript would look something like this.

```
function autocompleteHandler(elem)
{       
    var x = elem.parentNode;
    if(x.nodeName == "FORM") 
    {
        //do something with your form
    }
    else
    {
        autocompleteHandler(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What clumsy. Why not just using `elem.form` to get it as shown by the right answers of Christofer and Florian?

Answer (score 4):

Every input element has a `form` property that holds a reference to its parent form. You can pass `this` when calling the function, which will pass a reference to the input element, to the callback-function. Within the callback you can then read the form-property of the passed element, to get a reference to the form. The form element will in turn a have an ID-property which hold the forms ID.

A simple example would look something like this:

**Markup:**

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="autocompleteHandler(this);" />
</form>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function autocompleteHandler(elm) {
    alert(elm.form.id);
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjqWH/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use javascript's parentNode

```
var node = myElement;
var form = node.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `autocompleteHandler` function, you can get the id simply by using `this.form.id`.

From an input, you can get the form it belongs to in the `form` property.

Example:

```
function autocompleteHandler(val) {
    alert(this.form.id);
}
```